# Rails 2.3.8 make an active record dirty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord object. It is updated using the nested attributes of a parent object. The problem is it has some non-database fields which if set need to trigger an after_save event. The problem that I am having is that if no database attributes are updated the after_save never fires, but I need it to.

`ActiveRecord.partial_updates = false` is a default in my app. The save never happens...

I tried to update the `updated_at = DateTime.now` and it does not trigger the record to be saved. Only when one of it's other properties gets updates does the save actually trigger.

Note Rails 2.3.8

Comment: How do you specify the after_save callback?

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but does YourModel.partial_updates = false help matters any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I manually created a setter for the non database property and invoked `id_will_change!` which made the whole object dirty. This works for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Though I haven't tested it, it's possible that including `ActiveModel::Dirty` and telling it about those non-database fields will allow `ActiveRelation` pick them up.

More info: http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.3/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html